# Random Number Generator with a Seed

Tags: c, random, srand

I am generating random numbers by using srand(time(NULL)).
Any idea why it always gives just even random numbers? In my case its giving so. Please help i need odd numbers too. 
I need the set of 0s, 1s.
for eg : {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}

Comment: Not without seeing the code that you're using.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Please show us your code.

Comment: srand(time(NULL)) is just a seed. Show us your code where the function rand() is assigning numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of initializing the PRNG like initializing a variable ... You don't do

```
// pseudo-code
// print numbers from 1 to 10
do 10 times
    number_to_print = 1
    print number_to_print
    number_to_print++
end loop
```

Likewise, `srand()` should only be called once per program run.

```
call srand() // initialize PRNG
loop
    rand()
end loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

only one time at the beginning of your program, it "shuffles" the random sequence.

Then call

```
rand();
```

And it will return a number in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`.

If you want only 0 or 1 then you can try with

```
int n = rand() % 2;
```

or

```
int n = rand() & 0x01;
```